# Order object by id in the same order as the ids list

Tags: android, sorting

I have list of integer IDs. Lets say this list is `ArrayList<Integer>` or int[], it doesn't matter. I have another `ArrayList<Obj>` that contains the objects with the same ids like in the first list, but they are ordered in different order.

**I want to order the objects in the second list in the order as the ids in the first list.**

**EXAMPLE:**

```
FIRST LIST:  { 1, 5, 4, 8, 6 }
SECOND LIST: { Obj[id=5], Obj[id=8], Obj[id=6], Obj[id=1], Obj[id=4] }

RESULT LIST: { Obj[id=1], Obj[id=5], Obj[id=4], Obj[id=8], Obj[id=6] }
```

Can someone tell me an (efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a map:

```
Map<Integer, Obj> map = new HashMap<Integer, Obj>(secondList.size() * 2);
for (final Obj obj : secondList) {
    map.put(obj.id, obj);
}
for (int i = 0; i < secondList.size(); i++) {
    secondList.set(i, map.get(firstList.get(i)));
}
```

This runs in O(n), which IMHO is pretty much the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

A/ Create a matching id index list, such as:

```
1 -> 0
5 -> 1
4 -> 2
8 -> 3
6 -> 4
```

That's a reversed reference of your first list. It indicates the position of each id. A SparseIntArray is a good way of doing it:

```
SparseIntArray ref = new SparseIntArray();
for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {
    ref.append(firstList.get(i), i);
}
```

Then you need to sort your second list using a Comparator that uses the id of the Object and the ref table:

```
Collections.sort(secondList, new Comparator<Obj>() {
    public int compare(Obj t1, Obj t2) {
        return ref.get(t1.id) - ref.get(t2.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the middle of writing Etienne's answer when he posted it, so just for fun here's an O(N^2) solution with a smaller constant factor that doesn't create any objects:

```
    int[] first = { 1, 5, 4, 8, 6 };
    Obj[] second = { Obj[id=5], Obj[id=8], Obj[id=6], Obj[id=1], Obj[id=4] };
    int i = 0;
    while(i < second.length) {
        int ind = -1;
        for(int j=0;j<first.length;j+=1) {
            if(first[j] == second[i].id) {
                ind = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ind == -1) break; //Bad news
        if(ind == i) {
            i += 1;
        } else {
            Obj temp = second[i];
            second[i] = second[ind];
            second[ind] = temp;
        }
     }
```

Obviously the creation of second[] is pseudocode, but the rest will work if the arrays are equal length. I think this will be a little bit faster than Etienne's for very small data sets, but you'd have to profile both answers.